# How to compare two CSV files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've two **CSV** file named as **file1.csv** and **file2.csv** in **file2.csv** there is only one column which contain only five records and in **file1.csv** I've three column which contain more than thousand records I want to get those records which contain in **file2.csv**
for example this is my **file1.csv**

```
'A J1, Jhon1',jhon1@jhon.com, A/B-201 Test1
'A J2, Jhon2',jhon2@jhon.com, A/B-202 Test2
'A J3, Jhon3',jhon3@jhon.com, A/B-203 Test3
'A J4, Jhon4',jhon4@jhon.com, A/B-204 Test4
.......and more records
```

and inside my **file2.csv** I've only five records right now but in future it can be many

```
A/B-201 Test1
A/B-2012 Test12
A/B-203 Test3
A/B-2022 Test22
```

so I've to find records from my `file1.csv` at **index[2]** or **index[-1]**

this is what I did but it not giving me any output it just returning empty list

```
import csv 

file1 = open('file1.csv','r')
file2 = open('file2.csv','r')

f1 = list(csv.reader(file1))
f2 = list(csv.reader(file2))


new_list = []

for i in f1:
  if i[-1] in f2:
     new_list.append(i)

print('New List : ',new_list)
```

it gives me output like this

```
New List :  []
```

Please help if I did any thing wrong correct me.

Comment: `zip()` blindly pairs up elements in the order they appear in your source files. It won't help you find matches between the two files. To find matches, you basically need to compare all elements from list 1 to all elements from list 2.

Comment: I thought I gave you the idea already: you basically need to compare all elements from list 1 to all elements from list 2

Comment: Hello @Tomalak check I've removed zip but still I'm not getting any output

Comment: You're not supposed to "remove the `zip()`". You're supposed to  compare all elements from list 1 to all elements from list 2. Write a nested loop, for starters.

Comment: How would you do this on paper? Write down the steps. Now use that to write your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1: `pandas`

This task can be done with relative ease using `pandas`. [DataFrame documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

#### Example:

In the example below, the two CSV files are read into two DataFrames. The DataFrames are merged using an inner join on the matching columns.

The output shows the merged result.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', names=['match'])

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=df1['col3'], right_on=df2['match'], how='inner')
```

The `quotechar` and `skipinitialspace` parameters are used as the first column in `file1` is quoted and contains a comma, and there is leading whitespace after the comma before the last field.

#### Output:

```
    col1            col2            col3
0   A J1, Jhon1     jhon1@jhon.com  A/B-201 Test1
1   A J3, Jhon3     jhon3@jhon.com  A/B-203 Test3
```

If you choose, the output can easily be written back to a CSV file as:

```
df.to_csv('path/to/output.csv')
```

For other DataFrame operations, refer to the documentation linked above.

---

### Method 2: Core Python

The method below does not use any libraries, only core Python.

1. Read the matches from `file2` into a list.
2. Iterate over `file1` and search each line to determine if the last value is a match for an item in `file2`.
3. Report the output.

Any subsequent data cleaning (if required) will be up to your personal requirements or use-case.

#### Example:

```
output = []

# Read the matching values into a list.
with open('file2.csv') as f:
    matches = [i.strip() for i in f]

# Iterate over file1 and place any matches into the output.
with open('file1.csv') as f:
    for i in f:
        match = i.split(',')[-1].strip()
        if any(match == j for j in matches):
            output.append(i)
```

#### Output:

```
["'A J1, Jhon1',jhon1@jhon.com, A/B-201 Test1\n",
 "'A J3, Jhon3',jhon3@jhon.com, A/B-203 Test3\n"]
```

Comment: Hello @S3DEV thanks for your reply to my comment when I try to print output it's not giving me output it's giving me an empty list

Comment: Ok.  Check your source data and check the output of `match == j` (insert some `print` statements to debug).  There might be some leading / trailing whitespace which is making the equality test fail. The source data might need a bit of cleaning to match your stated case.

Comment: For clarity; I simply copied your text above and pasted it directly into two CSV files, and all worked as shown above.  Therefore, I presume the issue is your source data is different from what is posted above ... even if it’s whitespace.

Comment: (Sorry for all the comments.). Perhaps change `match == j` to `match == j.strip()`.  This will strip whitespace from the matching value from `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use sets or dicts for `in` checks (*complexity is O(1) for them, instead of O(N) for lists and tuples*).
2. Have a look at **convtools** library ([github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools)): it has `Table` helper for working with table data as with streams ([table docs](https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables.html#))

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# creating a set of allowed values
allowed_values = {
    item[0] for item in Table.from_csv("input2.csv").into_iter_rows(tuple)
}

result = list(
    # reading a file with custom quotechar
    Table.from_csv("input.csv", dialect=Table.csv_dialect(quotechar="'"))
    # stripping last column values
    .update(COLUMN_2=c.col("COLUMN_2").call_method("strip"))
    # filtering based on allowed values
    .filter(c.col("COLUMN_2").in_(c.naive(allowed_values)))
    # returning iterable of tuples
    .into_iter_rows(tuple)

    # # OR outputting csv if needed
    # .into_csv("result.csv")
)
"""
>>> In [36]: result
>>> Out[36]:
>>> [('A J1, Jhon1', 'jhon1@jhon.com', 'A/B-201 Test1'),
>>>  ('A J3, Jhon3', 'jhon3@jhon.com', 'A/B-203 Test3')]
"""
```